# generating a report in JIRA

Tags: jira

(note: I'm usually more thorough in doing my research before asking a question here, but I'm in a rush for a meeting this afternoon)

Is there an easy way in JIRA to generate a printable report for all issues (both open and resolved) under a specific component?

I want to include the description (but not subsequent comments) as well as the usual fields displayed in the normal issue list view (subject, issue #, reporter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! never mind, I found it, it's pretty easy in JIRA 4:

1. search in the Issue Navigator for the query you want
2. then click on the Views pulldown in the upper right of the screen, there's a view called "Full Content" that dumps everything.

I can live with seeing the comments included, for now....